# Access current page from OnResume in Xamarin.Forms application?

Tags: xamarin.forms

I need to make some computations in a subclass of `ContentPage` each time the page is shown to the user. I thought I cold use `OnAppearing` for that but that method is not called when the app enters foreground. So my question is whether there is a build-in mechanism to detect which page will be shown to the user from an `Application` subclass, and whether it is ok to call `OnAppearing` from `OnResume`?

Comment: why not use MessagingCenter to do this?

Comment: @Jason Yeah! Thanks for pointing that out. I'll take a look to see if I can come up with something using `MessagingCenter`.

Comment: @Jason using `MessagingCenter` I just added two lines of code to solve the problem. I'll gladly accept your comment if you put it as an answer.